# Frameworks for JavaScript UI Widgets?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put together a list of JavaScript UI widget frameworks for consideration in a project. Ideally it would be a library that has a range of ready made ui widgets, no dependencies on dom/js extention/manipulation frameworks like JQuery or Prototype, minimal additional cruft, such as Ajax API's and DOM selectors etc.

Here's what I have so far:

- qooxdoo,
- ScriptClient
- ExtJs

Could anyone suggest any other that are worth a look?

Please do not suggest, JQuery, Prototype, Mootools, Dojo etc, their primary focus is not to provide ui widgets.

Comment: The primary focus of Dojo Dijit (a sub-project of Dojo) is to provide widgets. Take a look.

Answer (score 5):

Answered here: [Your choice of cross-browser javascript GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218699/your-choice-of-cross-browser-javascript-gui) and here: [What are alternatives to ExtJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200284/what-are-alternatives-to-extjs)

Answer (score 3):

YUI (yahoo user interface) has a nice set of ui widgets.

Answer (score 3):

There is not so small list of [AJAX and JavaScript solutions](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/04/15/60-more-ajax-and-javascript-solutions-for-professional-coding/). I know, it is not some library, but maybe you'll find something useful.

Answer (score 1):

This [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)  is a nice comparison of different java script frames works. This comparison is based on different parameters. It gives insight into different aspects of frameworks.

Comment: personally I have worked with ExtJS. You can use it for commercial purpose with very little fee. And very nice support and a very active community.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion of Dojo is that it's actually *very* much orientated at providing UI widgets, not that I'd recommend it anyway.

I think you'll struggle with your limitations: every widget-like framework beyond the most trivial examples depends on some base JS framework to do the heavy lifting - and that's a good thing.

Comment: Specifically Dojo Dijit (a subproject) is all about widgets.

Comment: ["oriented"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/oriented-vs-orientated)

Answer (score 0):

Active Widgets (http://www.activewidgets.com) - very good controls that resemble those commonly found in Win32 and work very well in both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

[Rialto](http://rialto.improve-technologies.com) (Rich Internet Application Toolkit) is ajax-based cross browser javascript widgets library. Because it is technology agnostic it can be encapsulated in JSP, JSF, .Net, Python or PHP graphic components. The purpose of Rialto is to ease the access to rich internet application development to corporate developers. Ideally a Rialto developer have neither need to write or understand DHTML, Ajax or DOM code.

The target of Rialto is corporate web applications and not internet web sites.

Comment: Rialto ceased development in 2012.

Answer (score -2):

Sproutcore has a nice set: http://www.sproutcore.com/

Comment: Sproutcore says on [their About page](http://sproutcore.com/about/): **SproutCore is not for drop-in widgets**