# is there any javascript library to implement responsive design without media-queries

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Which of exist UI frameworks provide full responsive design tools on non-modern browsers?

I tried [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) with no success because their heavily usage of media-query which has not support on old browsers like IE-7

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218699/your-choice-of-cross-browser-javascript-gui

Comment: Due to the fact said browsers are old, there's very minimal support in them for responsive design, meaning such tasks become futile. Seeing as even Google has dropped support for IE7 & FF3.5, it might be worth considering doing the same yourself.

Comment: @Christian I can't find my answer on your preferred link, please describe more

Comment: @Death Unfortunately, I'm not decider and I should implement responsive at least on IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Adapt.gs](http://adapt.960.gs/).

It's responsible version of [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/), which was popular before Bootstrap and Skeleton. I'm not very familiar with it, but it's lightweight and seems to work fine in IE9@IE7 Mode.